# Xcode shortcut to open the document items list

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard-shortcut to open this awesome list (that I don't know the name of) ?

[image: List of pragma marks]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try <kbd>⌃</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd>

Also the other control + numbers to see the other dropbowns in that disclosure list.

You can see them and others in the Key Bindings section of Xcode preferences:

[image]

Comment: Voilà, thanks a lot! The mousepad won't be used for a couple of days now :)